# How to handle \(escape) character in regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this following script that will replace `"` and `a` characters with `\"` and `\a`.

```
'"replace'.replace(/"|a/g, "\\$&");
```

will result: `\"repl\ace`

Now I need is to replace the `\`(escape character) with `\\`. but trying the following code failed with exception `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /` in chrome console.

```
'"re\place'.replace(/"|a|\/g, "\\$&");
```

What is the possible workaround to replace the escape character in regular expression (in Javascript)?

**Update**

Simplifying the pblm, why 'rep\lace'.toString() results 'replace' and not 'rep\lace'?

Regarding the same, I have tried these code,

1. `"re\nlace".toString();` results `re` line break `lace`
2. `"re\xlace".toString();` results  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. May b since \x is not executable.

I think Javascript is executing the string value. But for what?

Comment: Didn't you try \\ to escape \??

Answer (score 1):

```
'"replace'.replace(/"|a|\\/g, "\\$&");
```

Answer (score 1):

The last `\` escapes the last `/`, you should escape it to make your regex look like

```
'"replace'.replace(/"|a|\\/g, "\\$&");
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1
The `\` needs to be escaped in regex:

```
"re\place".replace(/a|\\/g,"\\$&");
repl\ace
```

Problem #2
This `"\"` directly entered results in `""` - `\` again needs to be escaped:

```
"re\\place".replace(/a|\\/g,"\\$&");
re\\pl\ace
```

The point is, that a `\` says: Here we have a special char.
`\n` -> new line
`\\` -> `\`
`\x` -> error, because x is not defined as a char for something else

In other words:
If want to type `"re\nlace".toString();` then inside a string you have to type `"re\\nlace".toString();`

Maybe this helps you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: @Michel..I'm afraid this will not.. You have told to escape but have not actually escaped there.

Comment: @RohitJain I answered via mobile and something went wrong, so I switch to Desktop now, to correct it. But you did it already, so thanks ;-)

Comment: @Michel Thanks. the exception has gone now.But 're\place'.replace(/"|a|\\/g, "\\$&"); will result "repl\ace". That is 'escape char at p' disappers!! What I expect is  "re\\pl\ace" :(

Comment: 're\place'.replace(/"|a|\\/g, "\\$&");

Comment: 're\place'.replace(/"|a/g, "\\$&").replace(/\\/g, "\\\$&");   You can try this.. But I'm quite sure the first one should work..

Comment: Nope. Bcz 're\place'.replace(/"|a/g, "\\$&") results "repl\ace". And 're\place'.replace(/"|a/g, "\\$&").replace(/\\/g, "\\\$&"); result "repl\\ace"

Comment: I've edited my answer - now it should solve/explain everything.